# Eliminar un usuario usando PHP

Tags: formularios, php7, backend, eliminar, actualizacion

soy algo nuevo en esto de PHP y quisiera pedirles sugerencias. Es que quiero actualizar el estado del usuario a 2 ya que ese es el estado del inactivo.
Tengo una sesion y toda la información del usuario de esa session pero quiero saber si hay forma de que con solo un botón pueda cambiar ese estado. Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cuando la persona entra al módulo de actualizar tenga la opción de modificar, pero a la vez tenga esa opción de "eliminar" aunque el eliminar es solo un actualizar para cambiar el estado del usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo en codigo. En el index.php tengo un boton y en el js la función, en el php ya tengo el arreglo con los datos del usuario, pero nose como hacer que esos 3 juntos funcione ya que no sé cómo hacerlo si tengo un botón solamente

```
<div class=" row offset-s1 center-align">
  <i class="#7986cb indigo lighten-2 btn" onclick="EliminarUsuario()">Eliminar</i>
</div>




function EliminarUsuario(id){
Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Estás seguro?',
    text: "¡No podrás revertir esto!",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: '¡Sí, elimínalo!',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {


      Swal.fire(
        'Usuario eliminado',
        'Ya no podrá acceder al sistema con este correo.',
        'success'

      )
    } else {
        Swal.fire(
            'Usuario no eliminado',
            'El usuario no ha sido eliminado.',
            'error'
          )
    }
  });
}
```

En el PHP tengo una session donde tengo el usuario logeado, solo hace falta el evento

```
<?php
session_start();

//si existe la sesion
if (isset($_SESSION['usuarios'])) {
    $correo = $_SESSION['usuarios'];
    
    //Hacemos la conexion a la base de datos
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=educasen', 'root', '');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    //Hacemos la consulta para traer los datos del usuario
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT id, nombres_completos, estados_usuarios_id, correo FROM usuarios WHERE correo = :correo');
    $statement->execute(array(':correo' => $correo));
    $resultado = $statement->fetch();

    //Guardamos los datos en variables
    if ($resultado != false) {
        $nombres_completos = $resultado['nombres_completos'];
        $correo = $resultado['correo'];
        $id = $resultado['id'];
        $estados_usuarios_id = $resultado['estados_usuarios_id'];
    }

    //Hacemos la consulta para traer los grados
    $statementGrado = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM grados');
    $statementGrado->execute();
    $resultadoGrado = $statementGrado->fetchAll();

    //Recibimos los datos del formulario
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confipassword = $_POST['confipassword'];
        $grado = isset($_POST['grado']) ? $grado = $_POST['grado'] : $grado = null;

        $errores = '';
        $success = '';
        //Validamos los datos
        if (empty($nombre) or empty($correo) or empty($password) or empty($confipassword) or empty($grado)) {
            $errores .= "<script> Swal.fire(
                        'Opps...',
                        'Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente',
                        'error')</script>";
            $errores .= '<li class="#ef5350 red lighten-1">Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
        } else {
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = :correo LIMIT 1');
            $statement->execute(array(':correo' => $correo));
            $resultado = $statement->fetch();

            if ($resultado != false) {
                $errores .= "<script> Swal.fire(
                            'Opps...',
                            'El correo ingresado ya existe',
                            'error')</script>";
                $errores .= '<li class="#ef5350 red lighten-1">El correo ya existe</li>';
            }

            //Encriptamos la contraseña
            $password = hash('sha512', $password);
            $confipassword = hash('sha512', $confipassword);

            if ($password != $confipassword) {
                $errores .= "<script> Swal.fire(
                            'Opps...',
                            'Las contraseñas no son iguales',
                            'error')</script>";
                $errores .= '<li class="#ef5350 red lighten-1">Las contraseñas no son iguales</li>';
            }
        }

        //Si no hay errores actualizamos los datos
        if ($errores == '') {
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE usuarios SET nombres_completos = :nombre, correo = :correo, password = :password, grado_id = :grado WHERE id = :id');
            $statement->execute(array(':nombre' => $nombre, ':correo' => $correo, ':password' => $password, ':grado' => $grado, ':id' => $id));
            $success .= "<script> Swal.fire(
                        'Usuario actualizado',
                        'Inicie sesion con los nuevos datos',
                        'success')</script>";
            $success .= '<li class="#00e676 green accent-3">Usuario actualizado, inicie sesion con los nuevos datos</li>';
            $_SESSION['usuarios'] = $correo;

            //Esperar 0.2 segundos destruir sesion y redireccionar
            header("Refresh:0.2; url=login.php");
            session_destroy();
        }
    }

    //El metodo POST no me serviria ya que no esta en un formulario el boton
    if (isset($_POST['eliminar'])) {
        //Actualizamos el  $estados_usuarios_id a 2
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE usuarios SET estados_usuarios_id = 2 WHERE id = :id');
        $statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    }

    //Enviar el id a javascript
    echo "<script>var id = $id;</script>";
    
    
require 'views/perfil.View.php';
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}

?>
```

La intención es que al hacer clic sobre el botón haga lo que se muestra en las img de arriba. Sería de gran ayuda todos los aportes en este POST, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: @masterguru ya subí img del Código que tengo

Comment: Aparte de todo eso, mirando las imágenes, veo que lanzas el swall pero dentro no haces ninguna petición AJAX hacia tu PHP, por lo tanto no hace nada. Mírate [este ejemplo](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request) para conseguir enviar los datos a PHP.

Comment: @masterguru Es que ese es el punto, yo que le puedo enviar al php si el id de usuario esta en php y no lo muestro en el front como si fuera una tabla.

Comment: Creoq ue te contradices un poco. Si te fijas la propia funciòn **EliminarUsuario(id)** requiere de un parámetro (**id**) y sin embargo tu intentas ejecutarla sin en el onclick. Allí es donde debes poner el ID del usuario en cuestion, luego, en el swall, debes enviar ese **id** al PHP, y que el PHP haga su trabajo y devuelva un resultado (conforme lo ha hecho o no).  Recomendación: No permitas que el id de usuario pueda ser borrado por un usuario distinto.  O bien, si sabes que usuario está logeado no te hace falta el **id**, sino que lo puedes recuperar de la sesion y borrarlo.

Comment: @masterguru exacto, un usuario no puede borrar el id de otro; por eso tengo la session con todos los datos de ese usuario logeado. Segun tu que me aconsejas para poder iniciar, ya tengo los datos del usuario logeado como hago para recuperar esa sesión y borrarlo?

Comment: Supongo que debes localizar el id en la variable/matriz de $_SESSION. Haz un `print_r($_SESSION);` en tu script PHP para ver lo que contiene, y localiza el indice que tiene el ID usarlo en la consulta. Es decir, si fuera `$_SESSION['id']` entonces cambiarias esto en la consulta así: `$statement->execute(':id', $_SESSION['id']);`

Comment: @masterguru Si ya esa parte la tengo echa, tengo ese dato en especifico almacenado en una variable entonces me quedaría $statement->execute(':id', $id), teniendo esa Informacion cual seria el otro paso?

Comment: Pues lo que te decia antes del swall... debes enviar por ajax la petición a tu script por POST siguiendo [el ejemplo](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request) que te dije, pero agrégale el `Eliminar` como dato.  [Aquí](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/fetch-post-ajax-javascript.html) verás un ejemplo tambien de como hacerlo con el `fetch`.

Comment: Para poder avanzar, como te ha dicho @masterguru, pulsa en [edit] y agrega a la pregunta el código **como texto**. De paso, borra la "respuesta" que has aportado a tu propia pregunta. Esa área es para respuestas reales. Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, **pon el código como texto**, no capturas de pantalla. Si es incluso más simple para ti, copias el texto del código, lo pegas en la pregunta, seleccionas todo el bloque de texto una  vez pegado y pulsas en **`{ }`** en la parte superior del editor.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que ahora si se ve mejor, ya lo organice

Comment: Ahora sí. No olvides que siempre debes poner el código como texto. Las capturas de imagen no sirven para nada en estos casos. Ahora, pasando al problema que planteas aquí, ya te lo ha dicho @masterguru en sus comentarios, no estás mandando nada al servidor. Si quieres mandar el `id` o lo que sea al servidor, debes recogerlo en el cliente y mandarlo (puedes usar Ajax para ello o la nueva API Fetch). Otra cosa, todos esos `script` que tienes en el entorno PHP no son necesarios, Ajax o Fetch te permiten recibir una respuesta desde el servidor y actualizar el cliente, mostrando un mensaje u otro.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tu dices que el id lo tengo que enviar desde el cliente al servidor. Si yo tuviera una tabla con esa info pues me quedaría fácil, pero como hago cuando tengo esa info como el id del usuario que esta logeado en el servidor y requiero del evento de ese boton para que ejecute el script de eliminar? pero me sirve eso que dices para aplicarlo ya que si tengo mucho script

Comment: El planteamiento de la pregunta en sí mismo en confuso. Vamos a empezar por el principio, olvidando por un momento todo lo que tienes realizado. **Punto nº 1:** Si he entendido bien, tú quieres, desde una acción en el cliente (el click en un botón o lo que sea) modificar algo en el servidor. ¿Es correcta mi interpretación?

Comment: @A.Cedano si es correcto. Pero toda la info la tengo en el servidor y los datos los obtengo es por una session que creo el usuario al ingresar al sistema

Comment: Es que justo ahí tienes un error de interpretación. No es cierto que esa info la tengas **sólo** en el servidor, la tienes también en el cliente, puesto que, en el cliente, supongo, puedes ver un botón, el cual fue construido con código que se generó en el servidor. ¿Es así o no? ¿Cuando se generó esa interfaz gráfica, que incluye el botón o lo que sea, no disponías del dato que ahora requieres para mandar al servidor en la nueva consulta?

Comment: @A.Cedano con código generado del servidor pues no. Yo tengo dos archivos ejemplo: formulario.php que es toda la lógica y formulario.view.php que ahí si vendría siendo todo lo que se ve en pantalla. Yo toda esa info la tengo en formulario.php por así decirlo entonces es ahí en donde no se como podría usar ese botón para eliminar esos datos

Comment: Lo importante es que, cuando generas el formulario (que presentarás en el cliente) tienes a mano el dato que te interesa enviar posteriormente cuando se haga clic en el botón. Entonces, tienes que recoger ese dato (el `id`  o lo que sea) y enviarlo con la petición al servidor para que te busque, actualice, elimine o lo que sea por ese `id`. No sé si me explico. Lo que no queda claro aquí es siquiera el contexto, ni ese modo de comunicar, que es el habitual, entre cliente y servidor. Realmente `formulario.view.php`, aunque lo ves en el cliente, es un código **que se ha generado en el servidor**

Comment: @A.Cedano ya pude realizar lo que quería, muchas gracias me sirvió su consejo

Comment: @masterguru ya pude realizar lo que quería, muchas gracias me sirvió su consejo

Comment: Me alegro que ya lo tengas :-). En este sitio todos somos colaboradores y todos aprendemos unos de otros. Es por ello que te pido que, ahora que ya lo tienes, elabores tu mismo una respuesta con tu solución y la pongas, así la pregunta no quedará pendiente para siempre y además, si tu respuesta tiene algun fallo que quizás no ves (o algun efecto colateral imprevisto que aún no has visto), te lo podremos decir también y corregirla. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La solución es crear una tabla o un select donde se Envie el nombre del usuario logeado y el id del mismo, para después poderlo seleccionar y enviar ese id al archivo para proceder a eliminarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como tal no elimino pero este modulo va a actualizar el estado de ese usuario logeado para que no pueda acceder mas al sitio

```
//Actualizamos el estado_usuario_id a 2
$statement = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE usuarios SET estados_usuarios_id = 2 WHERE id = :id');
$statement->execute(array(':id' => $idRecibido));
$success .= "<script> Swal.fire(
            'Eliminado!',
            'El usuario ha sido eliminado correctamente',
            'success')</script>";
$success .= '<li class="#00e676 green accent-3">El usuario ha sido eliminado correctamente</li>';
$_SESSION['usuarios'] = $correo;
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).